# How to prevent refresh when using input fields

Tags: jquery

i had used the below function in the jquery to refresh the div but it is refreshing for every 10sec and when i am writing anything in that div also getting refresh. So, can any one give me the solution for it

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('.div').load('url');
}, 1000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds
```

function in jquery but there is a problem while writing any think in the input fields.

Comment: whats your demand? When do you want to refresh div?

Comment: You have a very confusing question. Plz refactor it or post some more code to see. This is not enough to give solutions with this piece of code.

Comment: on focus of fields when one edits, add a class to the div say 'edit' and in setTimeout before loading make a check if div got a class 'edit' or not

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: ah i just saw your edit. i did not quite understand your question.
i 
is this your problem? http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10305727-Keep-form-input-after-a-refresh-reload

You better use Jquery AJAX to refresh your div.

On this website you can find a nice tutorial.
http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/auto-refresh-div-content-jquery-ajax/

and here's a working demo: 
http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/auto-refresh-div-content/

an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto Refresh Div Content Demo | jQuery4u</title>
<!-- For ease i'm just using a JQuery version hosted by JQuery- you can download any version and link to it locally -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#content').hide();
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#content').show();
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#content').show();
            }
        });
        var $container = $("#content");
        $container.load("rss-feed-data.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('rss-feed-data.php');
        }, 9000);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <img src="loading.gif" id="loading" alt="loading" style="display:none;" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

iddin you code you refreshes all tags with div class (.div means with class name 'div')

you can set an id for your div and use it like:

```
<div id="update-div"></div>
```

and then:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('#update-div').load('url')}, 1000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds
}
```